# React Native app crashes / aborts right on start

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, crash-reports

I have `react-native` project, which is building and running fine in `debug` mode, but when I run it in `release` mode, app is opening on iOS simulator and closing in a 1 sec. then I'm getting crash report:

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Incident Identifier: EA3B9AF0-659B-4D59-853C-55D296B5801B
CrashReporter Key:   4F9B5A80-4C4A-7B84-FFBC-D58CA75F7C3C
Hardware Model:      MacBookPro14,3
Process:             Pixidium [51926]
Path:                /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E3C294DA-A44E-4DE1-8E76-F9BCA5887BCD/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9DAA0CEE-C04B-41EF-8C81-0AD00B1A241D/Pixidium.app/Pixidium
Identifier:          com.app.pixidium
Version:             0.1.0 (1)
Code Type:           X86-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd_sim [44115]
Coalition:           com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.E3C294DA-A44E-4DE1-8E76-F9BCA5887BCD [146482]
Responsible Process: SimulatorTrampoline [7556]

Date/Time:           2023-08-31 19:15:44.9798 +0400
Launch Time:         2023-08-31 19:15:44.4000 +0400
OS Version:          macOS 13.5 (22G74)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process: Pixidium [51926]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x7fff20422faa __exceptionPreprocess + 226
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x7fff20193ff5 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   Pixidium                               0x101395710 RCTFormatError + 0 (RCTAssert.m:166)
3   Pixidium                               0x1013aed1c __28-[RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invoke + 581
4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7fff2010670d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7fff201078df _dispatch_client_callout + 8
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7fff20114a27 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1045
7   CoreFoundation                      0x7fff203908f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
8   CoreFoundation                      0x7fff2038b169 __CFRunLoopRun + 2781
9   CoreFoundation                      0x7fff2038a1a7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
10  GraphicsServices                    0x7fff2b874d85 GSEventRunModal + 139
11  UIKitCore                           0x7fff246c14df -[UIApplication _run] + 912
12  UIKitCore                           0x7fff246c639c UIApplicationMain + 101
13  Pixidium                               0x10125f080 main + 80 (main.m:7)
14  dyld                                   0x10588f41f start + 1903

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7fff6030a202 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7fff6034cee6 pthread_kill + 263
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x7fff200fbcb5 abort + 120
3   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7fff20254692 abort_message + 241
4   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7fff20245dfd demangling_terminate_handler() + 266
5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x7fff20179ace _objc_terminate() + 96
6   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7fff20253aa7 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
7   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7fff20253a49 std::terminate() + 41
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7fff201078f3 _dispatch_client_callout + 28
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7fff20114a27 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1045
10  CoreFoundation                      0x7fff203908f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
11  CoreFoundation                      0x7fff2038b169 __CFRunLoopRun + 2781
12  CoreFoundation                      0x7fff2038a1a7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
13  GraphicsServices                    0x7fff2b874d85 GSEventRunModal + 139
14  UIKitCore                           0x7fff246c14df -[UIApplication _run] + 912
15  UIKitCore                           0x7fff246c639c UIApplicationMain + 101
16  Pixidium                               0x10125f080 main + 80 (main.m:7)
17  dyld                                   0x10588f41f start + 1903

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7fff60348bb0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7fff60348bb0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7fff60348bb0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7fff60348bb0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:: com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7fff603035c2 mach_msg2_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7fff6031173d mach_msg2_internal + 78
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7fff6030a5f4 mach_msg_overwrite + 692
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7fff603038aa mach_msg + 19
4   CoreFoundation                      0x7fff203904f9 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 316
5   CoreFoundation                      0x7fff2038ab9c __CFRunLoopRun + 1296
6   CoreFoundation                      0x7fff2038a1a7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
7   Foundation                          0x7fff20834204 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 209
8   Foundation                          0x7fff20834473 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 72
9   UIKitCore                           0x7fff24779ccd -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 464
10  Foundation                          0x7fff2085c8a9 __NSThread__start__ + 1068
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7fff6034d1d3 _pthread_start + 125
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7fff60348bd3 thread_start + 15

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7fff60348bb0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7fff60348bb0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:: JavaScriptCore bmalloc scavenger
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7fff603060fe __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7fff6034d758 _pthread_cond_wait + 1242
2   libc++.1.dylib                      0x7fff202a1f83 std::__1::condition_variable::__do_timed_wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l>>>) + 93
3   JavaScriptCore                      0x7fff31a81dae bmalloc::Scavenger::threadRunLoop() + 686
4   JavaScriptCore                      0x7fff31a81579 bmalloc::Scavenger::threadEntryPoint(bmalloc::Scavenger*) + 9
5   JavaScriptCore                      0x7fff31a82e87 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct>>, void (*)(bmalloc::Scavenger*), bmalloc::Scavenger*>>(void*) + 39
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7fff6034d1d3 _pthread_start + 125
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7fff60348bd3 thread_start + 15


Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000105931280  rcx: 0x00007ff7beca0e18  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000103  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007ff7beca0e40  rsp: 0x00007ff7beca0e18
  r8: 0x00007ff7beca0ce0   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000105931280  r11: 0x0000000000000246
  r12: 0x0000000000000103  r13: 0x0000003000000008  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x0000000000000016
  rip: 0x00007fff6030a202  rfl: 0x0000000000000246  cr2: 0x000000010334e000
  
Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148 
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
      0x105889000 -        0x105924fff dyld (*) <31e1c182-e611-3883-97a3-4334a21c90bd> /usr/lib/dyld
      0x10447e000 -        0x1044d7fff dyld_sim (*) <2a92fc99-72a9-38ed-8ddd-af4c25080124> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/dyld_sim
      0x10125c000 -        0x10238ffff com.app.pixidium (0.1.0) <b12b1067-bdd9-36c9-b9aa-29d0eb7a6829> /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E3C294DA-A44E-4DE1-8E76-F9BCA5887BCD/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9DAA0CEE-C04B-41EF-8C81-0AD00B1A241D/Pixidium.app/Pixidium
      0x1043ad000 -        0x1043b3fff libswiftAVFoundation.dylib (*) <171a808d-a714-3502-8c77-b1b37a5fa803> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
      0x10452b000 -        0x104908fff libswiftCore.dylib (*) <5739cb58-2c81-3e0b-8903-1716bdab660d> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib
      0x1043ca000 -        0x1043d2fff libswiftCoreAudio.dylib (*) <e1c3aadc-b003-361f-b841-c55aa7d6ecba> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib
      0x1043f0000 -        0x1043f0fff libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib (*) <e38e9ee9-964e-3636-a535-862ca08b6003> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib
      0x1043f9000 -        0x104403fff libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib (*) <33918134-0a00-37eb-8724-22cab45c62bc> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
      0x104427000 -        0x104427fff libswiftCoreImage.dylib (*) <0487a509-db4a-30df-8170-7957f2c2d5e5> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
      0x10442f000 -        0x104431fff libswiftCoreLocation.dylib (*) <b0a93c53-ecfc-3d3b-ba9e-1bee0f842e12> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib
      0x104c4e000 -        0x104c83fff libswiftCoreMedia.dylib (*) <d059fe58-2a57-322e-93a5-c030afa36898> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib
      0x10443f000 -        0x104445fff libswiftDarwin.dylib (*) <875befce-d2a2-3d08-ae05-e5b8872c4bf6> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/libswiftDarwin.dylib
      0x104d1a000 -        0x104d2ffff libswiftDispatch.dylib (*) <a1dbc32f-3f9b-3308-9c6a-8332f21842d0> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/libswiftDispatch.dylib
      0x104458000 -        0x10445afff libswiftMapKit.dylib (*) <0c5705d3-2bd2-307e-932f-4ac941b2bf1b> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/libswiftMapKit.dylib
      0x104465000 -        0x104469fff libswiftMetal.dylib (*) <3abd9369-a850-31d8-b9ae-c4c6b86a516b> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/libswiftMetal.dylib
      0x104d77000 -        0x104d78fff libswiftObjectiveC.dylib (*) <1b50fb46-af71-3841-a01e-f749762aad33> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
      0x104d86000 -        0x104d87fff libswiftQuartzCore.dylib (*) <485a5272-89f2-39b8-accc-15ad33fa0c07> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
      0x104d91000 -        0x104dd4fff libswiftUIKit.dylib (*) <68d0261e-238f-376e-8b9c-1986e6c00754> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/libswiftUIKit.dylib
      0x104e64000 -        0x104e65fff libswiftVision.dylib (*) <24ed270b-cf1b-356c-aa41-8026417261cc> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/libswiftVision.dylib
      0x104e70000 -        0x104eb3fff libswift_Concurrency.dylib (*) <947ed692-acaa-3259-8213-1ee199530b3d> /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E3C294DA-A44E-4DE1-8E76-F9BCA5887BCD/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9DAA0CEE-C04B-41EF-8C81-0AD00B1A241D/Pixidium.app/Frameworks/libswift_Concurrency.dylib
      0x104f00000 -        0x104f11fff libswiftos.dylib (*) <7bafc3dc-b2de-3783-9e43-f7fc44f09c86> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/libswiftos.dylib
      0x104f38000 -        0x104f52fff libswiftsimd.dylib (*) <0cd67ff3-75eb-3425-9524-7ac91c0b003c> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/libswiftsimd.dylib
      0x104f7e000 -        0x1050cffff libswiftFoundation.dylib (*) <da0f3834-488b-390c-b379-c81fbb3d06e1> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/libswiftFoundation.dylib
      0x1053c0000 -        0x1053ccfff libobjc-trampolines.dylib (*) <fa243b98-cc7f-31e2-bac8-ec3c06b91053> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
    0x7fff60302000 -     0x7fff6033bfff libsystem_kernel.dylib (*) <642737ce-21cf-3d87-a7b6-7eea2c080a7e> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff60347000 -     0x7fff60352fff libsystem_pthread.dylib (*) <3a3fa85c-f1fe-336c-bf68-924fc947ade3> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff20081000 -     0x7fff20103fff libsystem_c.dylib (*) <bb1043fc-b4af-33e4-a1f6-4904ec2e54f8> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff20244000 -     0x7fff20259fff libc++abi.dylib (*) <2e31f7d1-3df9-399f-a960-370bdace290c> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff20174000 -     0x7fff201a5fff libobjc.A.dylib (*) <583e6742-de52-3e41-863c-cdc43aa76767> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff20104000 -     0x7fff20148fff libdispatch.dylib (*) <36cbb11c-f0e3-3d0e-821f-1075f517e68a> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff20311000 -     0x7fff206aefff com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9) <9bfc8556-af16-311f-874e-374fa485fe2e> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff2b871000 -     0x7fff2b879fff com.apple.GraphicsServices (1.0) <e0b67f3f-c773-3408-9461-319c6e93665e> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
    0x7fff23ac2000 -     0x7fff24ef5fff com.apple.UIKitCore (1.0) <8fe99d0a-8703-3f7e-bbd1-be8d1d58f994> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
    0x7fff2071f000 -     0x7fff209bffff com.apple.Foundation (6.9) <c2a18288-4aa2-3189-a1c6-5963e370de4c> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
    0x7fff20299000 -     0x7fff202ebfff libc++.1.dylib (*) <a0dbcb81-ae08-3feb-bcbe-d10dc8d48bfb> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff309a9000 -     0x7fff31b93fff com.apple.JavaScriptCore (8611) <89cce14a-aa48-3994-a6ae-a77fd3a31043> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.5.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore

EOF
...
...
```

The command I'm using to run in `release` mode looks like:

```
react-native run-ios --configuration=release --simulator='iPhone 11 (iOS-14.5)'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem? I'm seeing the exact same crash in my app.

Comment: @Qw4z1 yes, I just posted as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the reason was that, I've accidentally removed:

```
import React from 'react';
```

The project were using old version of `React Native` and looks like it was sensitive to this "minor" change.